# How do I set up a basic mail server for the first time?

Tags: vps, email

I have a site running on a VPS, now I want to be able to receive mails at `info@mydomain.com`. How do I need to set up the server? And how should I set up the mail client on my PC to receive those mails? The server is running CentOS/RHEL.

I'll really appreciate if someone shed some light on the steps that need to be taken. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be more useful to future readers, you may want to update the subject of your question to something more specific.  I suggest something along the lines of "How to set up a basic mail server for the first time".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The steps:

1. Get the [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) for *mydomain.com* updated to point the [MX record/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) to your server;
2. Install the [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) of your choice (I recommend [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html), of course);
3. [Configure the MTA](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html) to receive mail from *mydomain.com* and deliver to local mailbox/es;
4. Install the [MDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent) of your choice (I recommend [dovecot](http://wiki.dovecot.org/), of course);
5. [Configure the MDA](http://wiki.dovecot.org/#Dovecot_configuration) for [POP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol)/[IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) access;
6. Set up your [MUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_user_agent) to retrieve/synchronize the mail.

Simple, right? ;)

Comment: You'd think ;-) but mail servers (MDAs and to a slightly lesser extent MTAs) are a frequent subject of complaints. For whatever reason they seem to be difficult to manage for some people. So don't _count_ on it being as simple as it sounds.

Comment: I was just being sarcastic there :) Looks like a lot of work, this.

Answer (score 1):

While its meant for debian based systems (swap apt for yum) http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/ is a really good, step by step guide to setting up a complete mail server

Answer (score 0):

Setting up [Google Mail](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) for your domain is trivially easy .. if it takes longer than 15 minutes (including the client) you are not paying attention to the instructions.

Comment: Too bad it's not fee anymore. It was an awesome way to quickly and easily get email setup on a domain.