# How to send a file as an email attachment on a Centos box?

Tags: centos, sendmail

I have tried the following:

mailx -s "test" abc@xyz.com

which says bash no command found.

also have tried :
Mail -s "test" abc@xyz.com

which says
/usr/sbin/sendmail: No such file or directory

even though the file name is valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For basic sending, just try `echo "Body Text" | mutt -a <file> -s "test" abc@xyz.com`.

Now, as Sleske mentioned, you might need to modify /etc/mail/sendmail.mc to configure this differently.  But if you're just wanting to send, and not receive, E-Mails locally, and you've already got an MX record for xyz.com, I think you should be all set.

Also, given your 'command not found' issues, double check you have MTAs installed.  use `rpm -q sendmail` or `rpm -q mutt`, and see if you find any packages.


--Chris

Answer (score 2):

```
(  cat body.txt 
   uuencode pic.jpg pic.jpg
) | mailx -s "subject" abc@xyz.com
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

You first need to set up a local mail server, and configure it to send mails (usually by passing them on to your ISP's relaying mail server).

See e.g. [How do I set up a basic mail server for the first time?](https://serverfault.com/questions/137894/how-do-i-set-up-a-basic-mail-server-for-the-first-time)